# AHK - Array is empty from StrSplit

Tags: arrays, split, autohotkey, strsplit

The script reads **IDs** from an .ini file. 
Each ID is separated by single spaces as delimeters.
Upon splitting the IDs into an array of substrings, the array comes up empty, though the output variable, **Recipients**, from **IniRead** isn't.

**some.ini file**

```
[IDs]
SampleID1 SampleID2 SampleID3
```

**some.ahk file**

```
#Persistent
#SingleInstance, force
SendMode, Input

IniRead, Recipients, some.ini, IDs

StringSplit, aRecipients, Recipients, A_Space
; this code wouldn't work either
; aRecipients := StrSplit(Recipients, A_Space)

F1::
   MsgBox % aRecipients[0]
Return
```

**AHK Version**: 1.1.24.01

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
aRecipients := StrSplit(Recipients, A_Space)
```

Would work, the thing with autohotkey arrays is that first element is **[1]** not [0]. So:

```
MsgBox % aRecipients[1]
```

Comment: Per @2501, it is a pseudo array, not an array. So, OP's original code would work like this: `MsgBox % aRecipients0` to show the number 3 (the zeroth element being the length), and `MsgBox % aRecipients1` to show the first ID (`SampleID1`).

Comment: There is a difference between **command** `StringSplit, OutputArray, InputVar [, Delimiters, OmitChars]` that @2501 explained, and **function** `StrSplit(String [, Delimiters, OmitChars])`. While `StringSplit` command does indeed return "pseudo array" to `OutputArray` parameter - the function `StrSplit()` returns array, where "zeroth" element being false and length being `array.Length()`. OP commented out his `StrSplit()` with note "; this code wouldn't work either".  It would.

Answer (score 1):

`A_Space` must be surrounded by `%%`:

```
StringSplit, aRecipients, Recipients, %A_Space%
```

The resulting array is not an actual object, but it is a pseudo-array. The first element holds the number of elements, the rest are the elements.

Syntax is in the form: `arrayN` where `array` is the name of the variable and `N` is the element index and may be a variable.

Thus to print it in your case the call should be:

```
string := "The array aRecipients has " . aRecipients0 . " elements:`n"
Loop, %aRecipients0%
{
    string := string . aRecipients%A_Index% . "`n"
}
MsgBox %string%
```